# What does "Camped deep" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "camped" mean in football (soccer) context?

MAN UNITED 1-0 MAN CITY

91: Every United player is **camped deep** in their half. Every City player is probing for an equaliser...

Comment: To **camp deep** - or be camped deep - (generally in their opponents half) means to be waiting / playing / moving in an area close to the opponents' goals. It is an attacking position assumed by a team that's anxious to score. To be camped deep in your own half would be a defensive position, generally to preserve a lead towards the end of a game.

Comment: It's just a metaphoric extension of the verb *to [make] camp* (derived from the noun meaning *a place where people stay temporarily*). Much the same usage occurs with ***stationed*** and ***deployed***, and it's worth noting that *all* of those verbs are commonly used when talking about the positioning of ***troops on the battlefield***, so those allusions (likening football to warfare) are likely to be picked up by the audience, even if only subconsciously. But if we ignore those associations, ***camped*** just means ***positioned*** in the cited context. And ***deep** = well inside*.

Comment: Both fine answers. Why not make them so?

Answer (score 3):

[Camp is defined here.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camp). The meaning in question is number 4 of the verb section:

> to take up one's position : settle down - e.g. camp out in the library for the afternoon

So the United players have taken up positions - deep in their half (of the field, 'deep' meaning far from their opponent's half) - and are not moving from them.

The word is often used in that sense in multiplayer gaming, where "camp" means to take up a specific position, often far from the action, and not move from it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably parsing the sentence wrong.

Where are the United players camping? Deep in their half. Not near the middle, but near their own goal.

In soccer terms, "depth" refers to the direction from goal to goal, and "width" to the other direction.